# Django Queryset Thread Safe Read

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, concurrency

I've been reading up a bit on concurrency with database transactions in Django.

My question is if you are simply getting querysets to use in a Django view for instance and just essentially perform read operations without any intention of making changes to the database, should the lines of code getting the querysets still be in a transaction, knowing the models could be updated in another thread?

If I seem to not be understanding something, feel free to let me know.

For example..

```
def some_function():
  ricky_obj = Model.objects.filter(name='Ricky')
  # maybe another thread deletes an object with the name bob at this very time.
  bob_obj = Model.objects.filter(name='Bob')
  do_some_stuff_here()
  return
```

Comment: Well by default django wraps every view in a transaction, hence the concurrent updates of other views are not seen by this thread (unless these were already commited before we entered the view).

Comment: I see thank you for clarifying.